# Python whois.whois returns a property object

Tags: python, pandas, whois

I'm running whois.whois on Python 3.5 as follows:

```
def simpleWhois(url):
    try:
        result = whois.whois(url)
        return result
    except Exception as error:
        print(type(error), error, url)
        return pd.Series.empty
```

On most URLs e.g. 'google.com' I get a Pandas Series, but on some example like 'www.usaa-a.com' an error is raised, and I get a 
    `<property object at 0x00000000XXXX>, Name: whois, dtype: object`.
Whose properties are they? How can I get to them? How can I test test that I'm getting this kind of result rather than a series, and perhaps overwrite it with an empty series if I can't get anything useful out of it?
Thanks!

Comment: `google.com` is a domain name, for which you can use `whois`, while `www.usaaa.com` is an hostname. In the second case try instead with just `usaaa.com` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand why I got a property object, but for this particular problem I came up with the following solution:

```
    def simpleWhois(url):
try:
    result = whois.whois(url)
    return result
except:
    error = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print("Error: %s, %s, for %s " % (type(error), error, url))
    return whois.parser.WhoisEntry.load(url, '')
```

i.e. return an empty whois entry.